# Is it possible to limit the pid of child processes in Linux bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pid

For example the bash pid is 3000, and I want to limit the child pid to be in the range [3001,3010].

I want this because I am writing a infinite while loop in bash, and the pid will explode.

```
while true;do
    something;
    sleep 5;
done;
```

Every loop spawned at least 3 child processes(true, something, sleep). So the pid whill grow at the speed of at least 3 per sec. After a time, ps aux will show an awkwardly big pid, I think it is not a good thing.

Comment: Why do you think that a "big" PID is "not a good thing?"  What do you mean by "the pid will explode?"

Comment: the pid is just a number. It's managed by the OS, so you don't need to worry about it at all.

Comment: I know that when pid exceeds a maximum number it will warp back, but I cannot resist to try not to let it happen.

Comment: You absolutely cannot avoid pid rollover, it will happen after the machine has been up long enough no matter what you do. All you are talking about is forced rollover in your given range which doesn't strike me as any more sensible.

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please edit your question to improve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIDs don't "explode". They are recycled by the kernel. You can see the maximum PID number in /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max. Of course, you can modify this value, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is totally impossible, since the pid is assigned by the *kernel* when it is running the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) syscall. A user-level application or library cannot change that. Indeed the kernel is at some time recycling pids, as [answered by Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26530353/841108).

<sup>You might do a big loop on `fork` and `exit` immediately the child process if its pid (with `getpid`) is unsuitable, but that approach is insane, since you might need to `fork` several thousands times before being lucky.</sup>

Perhaps [namespaces(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) could be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sane way to do that from user space, and no sane reason to want to.

If you are convinced that you have to solve this problem, and you have the sources to `something`, hack it to run an infinite loop with a `sleep` between iterations.  Then you will stay in the same PID forever.

(Or slightly more off the wall, hack Bash so that `sleep` and `something` are built-ins, too. For the record, `true` is already a Bash built-in, so it will not actually spawn a subprocess.)